# Why do I receive a syntax error when trying to set a property in a CASE statement?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nosql

Hello I am using Node4j and I am trying to change de properties of a relationship depending of it´s type , the code that I have is :

```
Start f=rel(1) MATCH ()-[f]->()
SET f.distancia=256
return CASE f
WHEN rel(f)='FERROCARRIL'
THEN SET f.tiempo=f.distancia/150*60, f.precio=f.distancia*0.23
WHEN rel(f)='AVION'
THEN SET f.tiempo=f.distancia/250*60, f.precio=f.distancia*0.6
WHEN rel(f)='BUS'
THEN SET f.tiempo=f.distancia/110*60, f.precio=f.distancia*0.25
ELSE
SET f.tiempo=f.distancia/100*60, f.precio=f.distancia*0.28
END
```

I also try putting in the `case rel(f)` instead of **f** but i obtained the same result.

It returns an invalid syntax error, how I can do this ?

PS: I need to obtain **f** by the id of the relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you can't set values in a `CASE` statement. To make it work you have to set the values in a `FOREACH` statement. So, in your `CASE` statement you can set an empty array for types that do not match and set a single item array for the one type that does match.

```
MATCH ()-[f]->()
WHERE id(f) = 1
SET f.distancia=256
WITH f 
, CASE type(f)
    WHEN 'FERROCARRIL'
      THEN [[1],[],[],[]]
    WHEN 'AVION'
      THEN [[],[1],[],[]]
    WHEN 'BUS'
      THEN [[],[],[1],[]]
    ELSE
      [[],[],[],[1]]
END as type_rel
FOREACH( x in type_rel[0] | SET f.tiempo=f.distancia/150*60, f.precio=f.distancia*0.23 )
FOREACH( x in type_rel[1] | SET f.tiempo=f.distancia/250*60, f.precio=f.distancia*0.6 )
FOREACH( x in type_rel[2] | SET f.tiempo=f.distancia/110*60, f.precio=f.distancia*0.25 )
FOREACH( x in type_rel[3] | SET f.tiempo=f.distancia/100*60, f.precio=f.distancia*0.28 )
RETURN type_rel, f
```

An alternate cleaner approach would be something like this...

```
MATCH ()-[f]->()
WHERE id(f) = 1
SET f.distancia=256
WITH f 
, CASE type(f)
    WHEN 'FERROCARRIL'
      THEN [150, 0.23]
    WHEN 'AVION'
      THEN [250, 0.6]
    WHEN 'BUS'
      THEN [110, 0.25]
    ELSE
       [100, 0.28]
END as factors
SET f.tiempo=f.distancia/ factors[0] * 60, f.precio= f.distancia * factors[1]
RETURN f
```